# How to avoid java Security Information popup?

Tags: security, java, client-certificate

Problem - Java security information popup appears when applet based application loads in the browser.

[image]

When I check *"Always trust content from the publisher"* and click run, the application runs and certificate is added to java user trusted certificates list.

[image]

When I run the application the next time, the Security Information popup does not appear.

My questions are -

***How can I avoid the security information popup for other users logging into the same computer?***

It is a shared desktop used by multiple users and every time a new user logs in and uses the applet based application, the security information popup appears.

***How can the certificate be added to a centralized location (perhaps system trustsore?) and not to user profiles so that whenever a new user logs into the computer and uses the application, the security warning does not appear?***

What I've tried until now:

- Added the client certificate to java keystore on the computer. After
  this I logged into the application again, the popup still appeared.
- Added client certificate to jre\lib\security\cacerts - it didn't help either.

Comment: Does [this procedure](https://www.wincert.net/microsoft-windows/how-to-import-java-certificates-to-the-system-store/) solve the problem?